# What does it mean $: in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was reading the following [tutorial](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html).

It talked about including files in a `Ruby` file like `require` :

> `require(string)` => `true` or `false`
>
> Ruby tries to load the library named string, returning `true` if
>   successful. If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it
>   will be searched for in the directories listed in `$:`. If the file has
>   the extension ".rb", it is loaded as a source file; if the extension
>   is ".so", ".o", or ".dll", or whatever the default shared library
>   extension is on the current platform, Ruby loads the shared library as
>   a Ruby extension. Otherwise, Ruby tries adding ".rb", ".so", and so on
>   to the name. The name of the loaded feature is added to the array in
>   `$:`.

I just want to know what is `$:` in Ruby and what does `$:` means.

Comment: Please review my updated post. I mean the `$:`.

Comment: Alias to `$load_path` Checkout http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/ruby-man-1.4/variable.html

Comment: `$:` is one of Ruby's [Pre-defined variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+variables)

Comment: @maximus it's `$LOAD_PATH`, Ruby is case sensitive

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is "$:" in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846426/what-is-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks, Everybody. I just test it in the `irb` showing all the path.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `$:` is one of the execution environment variables, which is an array of places to search for loaded files.

The initial value is the value of the arguments passed via the `-I` command-line option, followed by an installation-defined standard library location.

See [Pre-defined variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html), `$LOAD_PATH` is its alias.

Answer (score 3):

Its the load path

Just open in irb terminal and type this `$:`
This is what you would get. Ofcourse that depends on the ruby ur using.

```
2.1.1 :009 > $:
=> ["/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0"] 
2.1.1 :010 >
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby **$** refers to a predefined variable.

In this case, **$:** is short-hand for $LOAD_PATH. This is the list of directories you can require files from while giving a relative path. In other words, Ruby searches the directories listed in $:

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, `$` is a global variable, not a predefined one.